# Vue3 async composantes in Pinia store

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

i'm working with a Vue3 project with Pinia and i need to perform an async call in the state function.

I have a Pinia store made in this way to manage login

```
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: "auth",
  state: () => ({
    
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
    returnUrl: null,
  }),
  actions: {
    async login(form) {
      ApiService.post("/login", form)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.result) {
            const user = {};
            user.username = res.data.username;
            const appStore = useAppStore();

            const macaddress = appStore.mac.value;
            user.macaddress = macaddress;
            this.user = user;
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
            router.push(this.returnUrl || "/admin");
          } else {
            alert("auth error");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    logout() {
      this.user = null;
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      router.push("/");
    },
  },
```

I need to take the macadress value from a composable script, useAppStore which is made in this way:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { ApiService } from "@/services";

export default function useAppStore() {

  const mac = ref(null);

  const getMacAddress = async () => {
    const response = await ApiService.get("/getmac");
    mac.value = response.data.message;
  };


  getMacAddress();


  return { mac };
}
```

When i do the logo, the `appStore.mac.value` is always null. I cannot understand how to wait for it in the store script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must await the result of `getMacAddress()`, and then must also await `useAppStore()`. See my updated code with comments below:

**composable**

```js
export default async function useAppStore() { // is now async
  const mac = ref(null)

  const getMacAddress = async () => {
    const response = await ApiService.get("/getmac");
    mac.value = response.data.message;
  }

  await getMacAddress() // now uses await

  return { mac }
}
```

**store**

```
ApiService.post("/login", form)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data.result) {
      const user = {};
      user.username = res.data.username;
      const appStore = await useAppStore(); // now uses await
      ...
```